# Select query slow in oracle but fast in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize a simple sql query which takes 15ms to run in MySql database but takes around 600ms to run in Oracle database.

Following is the query:

```
select *
from APPEALCASE appealcase0_
where appealcase0_.caseNumber='BAXXXXX00' and appealcase0_.DELETED_FLAG='N'
```

I indexed the caseNumber column but still it doesn't help. Can anyone suggest me a solution to attain the same response time of 15ms in Oracle database too.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're not including the `deleted_flag` column in your index? Are there sufficiently few rows where that is "Y" to be concerned with? How many rows does this query return? How many rows are in the table? What is the query plan? Are statistics accurate? How are you measuring "response time"-- the time to fetch the first row?  The last row?  Are you measuring the time on the database server (excluding network time) or on the client (and thus including the time to fetch the rows)?

Comment: I don't want to include deleted_flag just to solve this problem...This query returns only one row and there are about 200,000 rows at this time and it grows in time. I am not sure about the query plan and statistics.Can you provide more insite. The time measurement is on the oracle client. Can we try partitioning ?

Comment: @Ashok Ambrose: how many of rows have the same `_caseNumber` but different flags? And 200k is too few to even start thinking of partitioning. "I am not sure about the query plan and statistics.Can you provide more insite" --- how about you google first?

Comment: You should be explicit in your question about the contents of these tables; i.e., do they contain exactly the same data in both DMBS?

Comment: What client program are you using to interact with Oracle?  Virtually all of them will have built-in options to generate query plans.  In SQL*Plus, you can do `set autotrace on` before executing a query to get a query plan printed out after the results of the query, for example.

Comment: This issue is resolved.Apparently the issue being jdbc fetching strategy of oracle works differently. I just made a change in the hibernate layer which fetches the record. The change is setting the maxresults of the query object to size 1 since the query retrieves only one record. I'm still unsure why this fixed but I suppose that oracle tries to bring 10 records at a time from the database server by default to avoid network traffic while bringing huge datasets. so by making its maxresult to be 1 it brings reduces the network traffic by providing a bandwidth for only one record.Not sure though

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need an index.  I would suggest:

```
create index idx_appealcase_casenumber_deleted on appealcase(casenumber, deleted_flag);
```

Comment: How about the opposite order with compression?

Comment: The OP did indicate that an index was created on `caseNumber`.  If there are a number of deleted rows, this composite index likely makes more sense but if there are very few deleted rows, that won't do much.

Comment: @JustinCave that's my exact second thought

Comment: Given that the same query works faster in MySQL, something is going on.  Perhaps it is a simple matter of a warm cache or of the statistics being out of date.